# Caching & Maintaining Data In Console Application Strategy [C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, console-application

Is there a strategy for caching data in a console application that is maintained after the console application is terminated and starts up again?

For example, when my console application starts up, 4 calls are made to my database which returns a fair amount of data. The rest of the application runs and uses these lists. When the console application starts up again at the next scheduled interval it will have to retrieve these four lists again. Is there a way to have those lists cached for a certain amount of time to reduce the amount of times I have to call the database?

My current set up is a Powershell script that just pings a URL on my website which obviously can cache these 4 lists and maintain them. However I think I need to move this function into console applications to remove the load from the IIS process as I've had some high CPU spikes on my server and Im assuming its to do with this code.

One idea I had was to give an API endpoint for these four lists in my website (so they can be cached) and call that from my console application. Is that the best way to handle this or is there a proper way of caching data and maintaining it after a console application has ended and started up again?

Comment: You could just dump the data to a binary file and read it again. But that wouldn't be much different then loading it from the database.

Comment: might a windows service be a better option?  If you use a standard console app, once it terminates, the cache is usually released too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a local file and store the values. Maybe in conjunction with a database or endpoint, adding some expire date to a tag in the file.

A local file access will be much faster then accessing a database or a any remote call. A remote call, lets say from a database or IIS endpoint could be used for your first load time.

Comment: I think this ended up being a bit more complicated as I have to also ping signalr. I think Im going to put this on hold for now.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you have no way to cache something for the app without a external resource

Comment: Nope none at the moment